# Автозапуск init скрипта от пользователя

Tags: gitlab, gentoo

Как в *gentoo* добавить автозапуск *init-скрипта* от нужного мне пользователя?

В консоли я запускаю так:

```
 sudo -u git /etc/init.d/gitlab start
```

С *gentoo* мало знаком и прошу помощи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

при запуске операционной системы, использующей систему инициализации `sysvinit`, может выполняться ряд т.н. *стартовых скриптов*, некоторые из которых запускают «демонов».

всё это происходит от имени *root-а* (это необходимое услови), и демон, при соответствующей конфигурации, может запускать потомков(-а) с более низкими привилегиями — для выполнения требуемых задач.

скорее всего, в стартовом скрипте *gitlab-а* именно так всё и реализовано. а как указать пользователя, от имени которого будет работать процесс(-ы), выполняющий реальную работу, по-моему, ясно [из ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18035582/4827341), вольный перевод которого ниже:

для смены пользователя, используемого *gitlab-ом* надо проделать следующее:

1. создать нового пользователя (или использовать существующего)
2. изменить пользователя *gitlab* в `gitlab.yml` на новосозданного
3. изменить пользователя *gitlab-shell* в `config.yml` на новосозданного
4. дать новому пользователю доступ к `gitlab-shell` и каталогу, используемому *gitlab-ом*
5. выполнить для нового пользователя все инструкции, касающиеся прав, из [документации по установке](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/install/installation.md)